# Asking for your own answer to be moved to comments section

Tags: discussion, comments, migration

As a new user of StackOverflow, I lack the reputation to comment everywhere. My question is: Is it allowed to answer a question, and flag it immediately for migration to comments or ask in the answer for it to be migrated? If not, should I just not comment.
Thanks

I looked on meta for answers that would answer my question, but the answers I found did not apply to this particular case

Comment: Just dont comment. Don't abuse the system.

Comment: This also might get you auto banned, posting comment answers.  I know if you post enough answers that get deleted you'll get auto banned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is to get the minimum rep (which is a pretty small amount) through either questions, answers or suggested edits, then you'll have the rep to comment.